# Fresh Reinstall of Windows 10 on a dual boot PC

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

For Reasons, I can't determine, my Windows 10 installation is completely borked - I'm rapidly losing space on my SSD because something is installing and taking up so much space on it, and is still doing so (Everything came back clean btw, scans hardware checkup, etc - No viruses).

So I'm going to do a fresh install - as in a complete and full removal of Windows 10, no reset or refresh, and install from square one on my SSD, to ensure that whatever this is doesn't come back or is still around if I do a reset. Now on my Secondary drive, an HDD, I am using Ubuntu Linux which I'm currently on right now. My question is will I have to reinstall Ubuntu as well to make sure I have a dual-boot system again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 will overwrite the master boot record (MBR), rendering Ubuntu unable to boot.  However, if you have the Ubuntu install CD/USB, boot from it and you will be able to rewrite the MBR to allow dual booting.

Comment: Just to amplify this answer a little, I find `boot-repair` much the easiest way to reinstall dual-boot. It is not installed in the 16.04 Live Boot (it may have been added since), so it might be a good idea to down-load its DEB file in advance, allowing you easily to install it when you boot the Live Boot disc. Alternatively, there is a stand-alone `boot-repair` ISO which you can boot instead of the LIve Boot.